# C# NewLine inside File.AppendAllText

Tags: c#, io

Writing a simple log for a program I'm doing and I'm getting troubles with FileAppendText()

I have this line to output various messages to the log:

```
File.AppendAllText( filePath, string.Format( "{0} {1}{2}", DateTime.Now, message, Environment.NewLine ) );
```

Problem with this is when I try to use it with a string like this

```
"This is my first line, \r\n this is my second line \r\n and this is my final line!"
```

It will just give this result

```
This is my first line, this is my second line and this is my final line!
```

when it should be

```
This is my first line, 
this is my second line 
and this is my final line!
```

Is there a way to fix this or do I have to do some dirty fixes?

Comment: Are you looking your first string on watch window in VS or something?

Comment: Did you try to open your file with NOTEPAD?

Comment: Your code is outputting three lines when used with the File.AppendAllText() in a testing application. See the other commenters for more explanatory questions.

Comment: I checked it out using the Text Visualizer in VS2013 and it looked fine. And yes I did open it with notepad (which is what will be used by the client). I have no idea why you got it to work Bernd Linde but it's not working on my machine! :)

I did a dirty fix with string.Split( new string[]{"\r\n} ) and then looped that and did an append on each of the lines. Might produce a few inconsistent dates due to execution time but it should be ok

Comment: you may need to set a breakpoint on that `AppendAllText`, and check the content of `message` at that time.

Comment: Change the encoding inside notepad when you open the file. some of the character sets behave strange with escape characters like /n and /t. UTF-8 should work in most cases.

Comment: Write a simple console application that does nothing but call `AppendAllText` with that string. Run it. See if it does what you expect. If not, edit your question and add that test program. What you describe doesn't seem possible, so there's something you're not telling us.

Answer (score 0):

`File.AppendAllText` does not modify the string that you pass in. You miust be misinterpreting what you are seeing.

Probably, the tool that you use to look at the file contents has a special way of showing them. It does not support rendering newlines. Use notepad.exe.

Maybe the question is based on wrong data. When you write `line, \r\n this` you should get two spaces. But your sample text does not have two spaces (`line, this`). Are you even showing us the exact thing you passed in and got out?!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same problem using Environment.NewLine instead of \r\n.